# Simplifying != if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm scratching my head trying to find a more compact version of this if statement,

```
if a != b and a != c:
    foo()
```

Where all conditions are not boolean.
I could imagine that it would be tedious to write if there were more than 2 conditions to check for.

I also tried:

```
if a != (b and c):
    foo()
```

But (b and c) depend on their corresponding bool values rather than comparing equivalence to a.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why do you want to make it more compact? What is your objective? If you hope to get better performance, then what you have if probably the best solution,

Comment: My objective is readability. If I had many more conditions (b, c, d, e...) that I had to check for non-equivalence, I could imagine it would be too much to look at.  It makes more sense to me that the same variable that is being checked should only appear once.

Comment: What was the purpose of your edit after two years?

Comment: @S.B Was testing it out to see if it would award the Excavator badge... guess it can't be your own post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use

```
if a not in [b, c]:
    foo()
```